# How to change SoftDelete data format with Eloquent?

Tags: eloquent, soft-delete

I need to use Eloquent SoftDelete, but in my company, the DB I'm using have a '***actif***' column instead of a '***deleted_at***' column, which is not a dateTime column.

The '***actif***' column is char(1), and SoftDelete needs a dateTime column.
And I don't know how-to change that.

I changed the column name, from deleted_at to actif with
**const DELETED_AT = 'ACTIF';**

Just addind **use SoftDelete;** in the code raises a
**InvalidArgumentException :**
**A four digit year could not be found Data missing**
...\vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Traits\Creator.php